# Change image src when accordion is opened ,Angular

Tags: angular

In my html I have this:

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-2 col-2 collapsedData" >
          <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-controls="collapseTwo">
            <img src="downArrow.svg">
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
      <p> Some text that displays</p>
      </div>
```

When the downIcon is clicked, the class collapsed gets removed, and aria-expanded becomes true.

Is there a way to use these two changed values, so that on the Img tag I have something like ;

```
 *ngIf aria-expanded=true, then display this image.
 else display another image.
```

I need to shift between arrow up and arrow down.
Can I bind these attributes to an ngIf ?

Comment: you can <img *ngIf="collapsed" src="upArrow.svg"><img *ngIf="!collapsed" src="dowArrow.svg"> or use a variable"imagen" and use <img [src]="imagen">

Comment: That doesn't work. How do I just write an ngIf inside the img tag. Where does it get the "collapsed" attribute from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a property in your component class that will be `true` when the component is collapsed and `false` when it is open.

```
export class MyComponent {
  collapsed: boolean = false;
  // ...etc
}
```

Then, bind to the `click` event in your template, so you change `collapsed` from `false` to `true` and vice versa. And use a ternary operator to change the image path inside the `src` property of `img`

```
 <a class="collapsed"
   data-toggle="collapse" 
   data-parent="#accordion" 
   href="#collapseTwo" 
   aria-expanded="false"
   aria-controls="collapseTwo"
   (click)="collapsed = !collapsed">
   <img [src]="collapsed ? 'downArrow.svg' : 'upArrow.svg'">
 </a>
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!!